# Jasmine with Angular 13: debugElement.query returns null

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to set an unitary test but the *const clickedRow = debugElement.query(By.css('[data-testid="store"]'))* is null. I know I have a ngFor there, but even if I queryAll with a class attribute, I get an empty array.

I would like to test when the data-testid="store" element is clicked, the function onClickItem is called after that.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column px-5 py-5">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
    <h1>Stores</h1>
    <app-button-primary class="ms-auto" type="filled">
      Add a Store
    </app-button-primary>
  </div>

  <div
    class="d-flex w-100 align-items-start justify-content-start gap-5 px-2 py-3"
  >
    <mdb-form-control class="mt-2 w-50">
      <div class="input-group border rounded">
        <span class="input-group-text border-0" id="basic-addon1"
          ><i class="fas fa-search"></i
        ></span>

        <input
          mdbInput
          type="search"
          class="form-control rounded border-0"
          placeholder="Ex. Giant Food."
          aria-label="Ex. Giant Food."
          aria-describedby="search-addon"
          id="search-input"
          (keyup)="search($event)"
          (search)="this.clearInputSearchbar($event)"
        />
      </div>
    </mdb-form-control>
  </div>
  <div class="datatable flex-fill d-flex w-100 mt-2">
    <table
      mdbTable
      mdbTableSort
      #table="mdbTable"
      #sort="mdbTableSort"
      [sort]="sort"
      [dataSource]="this.stores"
      class="table datatable-table"
    >
      <thead class="datatable-header">
        <tr>
          <th
            *ngFor="let header of columns"
            [mdbTableSortHeader]="header"
            scope="col"
          >
            {{ header | titlecase }}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody
        class="datatable-body"
        *ngIf="table.data?.length! > 1; else noMatches"
      >
        <tr
          *ngFor="let data of table.data"
          scope="row"
          (click)="this.onClickItem(data.fkey)"
          class="clickable"
          data-testid="store"
        >
          <td>
            {{ data.name }}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ data.address }}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ data.region }}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ data.lastVisit | date: "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm a" }}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ data.products }}
            {{ data.products > 1 ? "products" : "product" }}
          </td>
          <td><i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical"></i></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<ng-template #noMatches>
  <table *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <i>No matching results found</i>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</ng-template>
```

And this is the unitary test that fails:

```
fdescribe(StoreListPageComponent.name, () => {
  let component: StoreListPageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<StoreListPageComponent>;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;
  let fakeStoreService: StoreService;
  
  beforeEach(async () => {
    
    fakeStoreService = jasmine.createSpyObj<StoreService>('StoreService', {
      onCLickItem: undefined,
      getStoreWithVisit: undefined,
      getStoresByCompanyProjectId: undefined,
    });

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule, MdbTableModule],
      declarations: [StoreListPageComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: StoreService, useValue: fakeStoreService },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StoreListPageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
  });

  fit('calls onClickItem function when store name is clicked', () => {

    const clickedRow = debugElement.query(
      By.css('[data-testid="store"]')
    );

    console.log(clickedRow); // this log is null

    const event = makeClickEvent(clickedRow.nativeElement);
    clickedRow.triggerEventHandler('click', event);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fakeStoreService.onCLickItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you mocking `table.data` to have data and not be an empty array?

Comment: Using ```fixture.whenStable().then(() => {})``` apparently fixed the issue. I can see the retrieve array now.